# Split string to multiple columns and insert into temp table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, openrowset

My aim is to get the rows of a table that are comma delimited and split them into different columns. So I searched the net and found this stored procedure and it works fine. However if I want to place it in a temporary table I have to use something like this:

```
SELECT * INTO #Pass FROM 
OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=ORA\VENICE;Initial Catalog=VeniceDB;Trusted_Connection=yes;', 
'set fmtonly off EXEC VeniceDB.dbo.Split ''Green %''')
```

The problem is that when I use this and the stored procedure does not return any values then I get the following error:

> Msg 7357, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
>   Cannot process the object "set fmtonly off EXEC VeniceDB.dbo.Split 'Green%'". The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "(null)" indicates that either the object has no columns or the current user does not have permissions on that object.

Anyone know a workaround?

Comment: Is the stored procedure on a different server?

Comment: No. Same server same database. Its the only way I found that I can select * INTO a temporary table without me having to create the table before hand. This is because the stored procedure returns different number of columns each time that are not defined before hand.

Comment: Ah, I see.   Well, you could precede the "SELECT..INTO" with an IF that checks to see whether the procedure should return any rows, and if not, it does something else besides the SELECT INTO.

Comment: I tried it....its easy to do...it doesn't work...still the same error message

Comment: Not sure I understand how you have rows that are delimited and you want to turn them into columns. Are you saying that you have values in each row that are delimited and you want to split the string and dynamically generate the columns? There are a lot of easier way to do that.